# How to delete last row from table in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a homework that ask me to get all data from an xml and show it into a table that displays a "th" with the "td" Titulo, Autor, Año.
This "th" have to be repeated every 5 rows, but if last row doesn't contains any data from the xml, this "th" shouldn't appear in last position.

### The code for the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="biblioteca.xsl"?>
<biblioteca>
  <libro>
    <titulo>La vida está en otra parte</titulo>
    <autor>Milan Kundera</autor>
    <fechaPublicacion año="1973"/>
  </libro>
  <libro>
    <titulo>Pantaleón y las visitadoras</titulo>
    <autor fechaNacimiento="28/03/1936">Mario Vargas Llosa</autor>
    <fechaPublicacion año="1973"/>
  </libro>
  <libro>
    <titulo>Conversación en la catedral</titulo>
    <autor fechaNacimiento="28/03/1936">Mario Vargas Llosa</autor>
    <fechaPublicacion año="1969"/>
  </libro>
  <libro>
    <titulo>La vida está en otra parte</titulo>
    <autor>Milan Kundera</autor>
    <fechaPublicacion año="1973"/>
  </libro>
  <libro>
    <titulo>Pantaleón y las visitadoras</titulo>
    <autor fechaNacimiento="28/03/1936">Mario Vargas Llosa</autor>
    <fechaPublicacion año="1973"/>
  </libro>
  <libro>
    <titulo>Conversación en la catedral</titulo>
    <autor fechaNacimiento="28/03/1936">Mario Vargas Llosa</autor>
    <fechaPublicacion año="1969"/>
  </libro>
  <libro>
    <titulo>La vida está en otra parte</titulo>
    <autor>Milan Kundera</autor>
    <fechaPublicacion año="1973"/>
  </libro>
  <libro>
    <titulo>Pantaleón y las visitadoras</titulo>
    <autor fechaNacimiento="28/03/1936">Mario Vargas Llosa</autor>
    <fechaPublicacion año="1973"/>
  </libro>
  <libro>
    <titulo>Conversación en la catedral</titulo>
    <autor fechaNacimiento="28/03/1936">Mario Vargas Llosa</autor>
    <fechaPublicacion año="1969"/>
  </libro>
  <libro>
    <titulo>Conversación en la catedral</titulo>
    <autor fechaNacimiento="28/03/1936">Mario Vargas Llosa</autor>
    <fechaPublicacion año="1969"/>
  </libro>  
</biblioteca>
```

---

And this is my xsl code:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Biblioteca</h1>
        <hr style="text-align:left;"/>
        <br/>
        <table>   
          <tr id="s" bgcolor="#FFB6C1">
            <th>Titulo</th>
            <th>Autor</th>
            <th>Año</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="biblioteca/libro">                     
            <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="titulo"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="autor"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="fechaPublicacion/@año"/></td>              
            </tr> 
            <xsl:if test="position() mod 5 = 0">
              <tr  bgcolor="#FFB6C1">
                <th>Titulo</th>
                <th>Autor</th>
                <th>Año</th>
               </tr>
            </xsl:if>            
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table> 
      </body>    
    </html>
  </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

What I guess is that it need an xsl:if that where if last()="th" won't show but I have search for hours and I can't find a solution or if I found, I did not undestand because are too complicated and didn't undestand the code (I'm studying).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not post the expected result, so I am somewhat guessing here.

If you want to repeat the header row after every 5 data rows, then the simplest solution, IMHO, is to put it **before** every row that is the first in a group of 5 rows:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/biblioteca">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>Biblioteca</h1>
            <table border="1"> 
                <xsl:variable name="header-row">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Titulo</th>
                        <th>Autor</th>
                        <th>Año</th>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:variable>  
                <xsl:for-each select="libro[position() mod 5 = 1]"> 
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$header-row"/>  
                    <xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::libro[position() &lt; 5]"> 
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="titulo"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="autor"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="fechaPublicacion/@año"/>
                            </td>              
                        </tr> 
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table> 
        </body>    
    </html>
</xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your XML example, this will produce:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Michael, it was actualy what I was looking for. My problem was in first place that I didn't know how to use xPath very well because the book that We have for learning that is useless and doesn't explain anything at all about it, and my second problem was that I didn't know what to search to solve that, because all the information I found on internet was too specific and too advanced for my level. I am very grateful to you